# How to Select all Property Except one from Graph API message?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there any way to Select all Property Except one from Graph API message?

Query: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/albert@*****.onmicrosoft.com/mailFolders/inbox/messages?select=*

Is there any way other than manually giving every property in select?

The need to skip the property to reduce the API response time.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario a bit? Why don't you just $select the properties you care about, instead of getting all of them (minus the one you want to exclude)?

Comment: Need is API to return all property except "message body". Just to know the possibility to skip the one, instead of selecting all 25+ property.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

According to the official [Microsoft Graph API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter) on the select parameter there is no option to exclude one or more properties:

> Use the $select query parameter to return a set of properties that are different than the default set for an individual resource or a collection of resources. With $select, you can specify a subset or a superset of the default properties.

> In general, we recommend that you use $select to limit the properties returned by a query to those needed by your app. This is especially true of queries that might potentially return a large result set. Limiting the properties returned in each row will reduce network load and help improve your app's performance.

> In v1.0, some Azure AD resources that derive from directoryObject, like user and group, return a limited, default subset of properties on reads. For these resources, you must use $select to return properties outside of the default set.